# for loop script only executing fully on last file in the directory

Tags: python, bash, for-loop, bioinformatics

I am attempting to run a for loop with prokka on ~300 files. When I run the code, it creates a new file folder for each sample that contains the .log file - all seems fine here. However, when it begins to run the next piece of code that initiates the genome annotation, prokka only runs on the last file in the series.

I have tried just about every iteration I can think of, and I am still coming up against a wall. If someone could send me down the right path, I would be grateful!

```
cd /file/directory

for F in *.fasta;

do
     N=$(basename "$F" .fasta);
     prokka --locustag "$N" --outdir "$N" --prefix "$N" --compliant --metagenome --coverage 90 "$F";
done
```

prokka version 1.14.5 and working in bash script

Thanks!

Megan

Comment: N=$(basename "$F" .fasta); —> F already contains .fasta ?

Comment: Maybe ... I copied the format of the loop code from the prokka developer, so I haven't really played around with that piece. Regardless, it doesn't seem to be the main problem. The code appears to work fine, other than the "prokka --locustag ..." line, which is not cycling through my full list of files. It only runs for the last file in the series (after new folders have been generated for all samples).

Comment: Don’t know prokka. Try to post on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ too

Comment: N=$(basename "$F" .fasta); —-> first $ not needed

Comment: RE: $ - when I do that it creates a file called basename, rather than individual output files for each sample. And thanks for the tip on the bioinformatics page and for the help!

Comment: for F in *.fasta; ——> remove ;

Comment: for F in *.fasta; its fine

Comment: N=$(basename "$F" .fasta); —> F already contains .fasta ?  ---> wrong !! basename "$F" .fasta just strip .fasta from F

Comment: Does  just  < do prokka "$F"  > works ? According to https://github.com/tseemann/prokka/blob/master/README.md should